# Unity-Character Continues Moving when Locked onto enemy

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Ok so here's my issue, I have a script that allows me to lock on to and orbit an enemy target. The problem is if my character is moving when pressing the lock on button the character will continue moving in whatever direction it was going before the button was pressed regardless of any more button presses save for the opposite direction.

This doesn't happen when I'm stationary, if my character stands still and I press the lock on button everything works fine. It's only when I'm moving.

I'm not sure if this is enough information, or what else someone might need to better understand but here is my script:

```
if (GetComponent<DetectedEnemies>().locked)//checks bool to see if lockOn button was pressed
{
    mainCam.SetActive(false);//turns off main cam
    lockCam.SetActive(true);//turns on lockOn cam

    movesetting.tarObject = GetComponent<DetectedEnemies>().Closest;//target object will be the closest enemy to player

    this.transform.LookAt(movesetting.tarObject.transform.position);//player will look at the target object at all times

    if (currXRot.x > maxXRot.x)//if the current x rot of this object exceeds the maxXRot it can go...
        currXRot.x = maxXRot.x;//it gets reset

    transform.Translate(Vector3.right * movesetting.speed * Time.deltaTime * turnInput);//orbits around the target object
    transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * movesetting.speed * Time.deltaTime * forwardInput);//in control of moving towards and away from target
}
```

Any and all help is greatly appreaciated, thank you in advance. If you need more info or if something isn't clear please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a second speed variable which you use for the orbiting speed. Then if the player is locked set the first speed variable to 0  and when the player isn't locked set the orbiting speed variable to 0. Something like this: (I use 5 as an example)

```
if(GetComponent.<DetectedEnemies>().locked) {

speed = 5;
orbitSpeed = 5;
} else {

speed = 5;
orbitSpeed = 0;
}
```